# Bash - How to remove similar (not identical) lines? Grep? Sed? Awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I need to remove similar (not identical) lines from a file. e.g.

```
file.txt

/Bota-Espaco-Fashion-Com-Tachas-e-Cristais-Bege-1472878.html#botas
/Bota-Raphaella-Booz-Cano-Curto-2-Fivelas-Vermelha-1458535.html#botas
/Bota-Dumond-Country-3-Fivelas-Caramelo-1481004.html#botas
/Bota-Espaco-Fashion-Com-Tachas-e-Cristais-Bege-1472878.html
/Bota-Raphaella-Booz-Cano-Curto-2-Fivelas-Vermelha-1458535.html
/Bota-Dumond-Country-3-Fivelas-Caramelo-1481004.html
```

Wanted results: (unique lines ending with #botas)

```
/Bota-Espaco-Fashion-Com-Tachas-e-Cristais-Bege-1472878.html#botas
/Bota-Raphaella-Booz-Cano-Curto-2-Fivelas-Vermelha-1458535.html#botas
/Bota-Dumond-Country-3-Fivelas-Caramelo-1481004.html#botas
```

Any handy solution?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: What happens if you don't have a line with that suffix?

Comment: @drum I have no idea how to do it

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Things don't work :(

Comment: @user3196587 it is an understatement in saying the solution is straight forward. The reason no one is responding is because Stack Overflow is not a place where other people do your work for you.  I recommend reading up on the tools you tagged your question with, especially [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

Comment: @MrAlias "Stack Overflow is not a place where other people do your work for you"... ok, but I think it´s a place where people may help each other. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F\# '!a[$1]++' your_file.txt
```

Output:

```
/Bota-Espaco-Fashion-Com-Tachas-e-Cristais-Bege-1472878.html#botas
/Bota-Raphaella-Booz-Cano-Curto-2-Fivelas-Vermelha-1458535.html#botas
/Bota-Dumond-Country-3-Fivelas-Caramelo-1481004.html#botas
```

Comment: Welcome. You can also read the manual if you're using GNU awk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html